# How to solve connection issues with IBM DB2 database

Tags: c#, .net, db2

I've been trying to connect to DB2 IBM Database but I have this issue:

"CLI connection to database server failed due to licensing problem (SQL1598N, SQLSTATE=42968)".

I'm using
IBM.Data.DB2 (dll) in a .NET console project.

Comment: https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/forums/html/topic?id=03c676c4-9ebc-4b82-a9f9-2bc4c362d08d

Comment: See if this helps: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45955410/php-connecting-to-ibm-db2-failed-because-of-licensing-sqlstate-42968